# What is optimal for a government to encourage people to wish for to boost economic growth?

Tags: magic, government

A world with a similar tech level to ours has discovered that randomly magical beings will have random encounters with magical beings who will offer wishes for some service or kindness. These wishes can have vast consequences, but are always what they have called end neutral. While they can move things huge distances, they can't create new knowledge or materials.

If you wish for massive wealth say, a relative might die and leave you money, or a bank might have all their money stolen. If you wish for world peace, the wish giver might deliver every weapon in the world to you personally.

The wishes are limited to our solar system, and can't mess with large stellar bodies or cause mass casualties. Meta wishes backfire as there seems to be some sort of hidden regulation of magical creatures that stops you doing much after wishing for more wishes or magical powers or ongoing effects. They don't seem to have any other limitations, and the wish givers are generally altruistic if somewhat insane in morality, and try to give people the spirit of what they want.

What wishes are ideal for the government to encourage citizens to wish for to maximize their economic growth? They are tired of people using genies to rob banks.

Summary of limitations-

Can't create things, only transport them from location to location.

Can't cause mass deaths.

Can't damage stellar bodies the size of moons or bigger.

Can't impact things outside solar system.

Meta wishes don't work.

Comment: Brainstorming is increasingly discouraged, y'know.

Comment: The economy isn't subjective- it has fixed numbers, and there are clearly better or worse answers. Robbing banks probably isn't great for the economy, other things would be. As such, the grounds are objective, and this is not brainstorming.

Comment: *The economy isn't subjective* **Citation Needed**. Since the best and brightest economists aren't in agreement on how to solve economic problems, and consistently fail to correctly predict the outcomes of economic policy, how do you expect there to be a single specific answer to this question?

Comment: You're misinformed. The best and brightest economists do generally agree on how to solve a lot of economic issues. https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=6575443 so there is consensus about a lot of economic issues. We see that less on TV because TV is driven by politics, not evidence based research.

Comment: From the article you linked *"Economists are genuinely divided on some other issues, though, such as the minimum wage. Thirty-eight percent say the minimum should be increased, while 47 percent want it eliminated all together."* Seems like there are important questions with a pretty clear split. If the economy wasn't subjective then you'd wouldn't expect such a divergence in *opinions*.

Comment: Sorry, but VTC. From the [help/on-topic], "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." Even a small city government would have a very hard time making such choices in an objective manner. The idea that a national government could do it is mind boggling. Consider the U.S. government. All 15 executive agencies would have their own, independent criteria. Not to mention the hundreds of subgroups.

Comment: Other sciences disagree on important issues as well, particularly ones to do with the ethical treatment of the poor. Science doesn't rely on everyone agreeing about ethical questions. And I didn't ask what the government should do, I asked what would be optimal to do for the economy. In my story they may or may not follow that suggestion, but knowing generally good options is helpful in evaluating choices of characters.

Comment: I won't argue about economy, already talked about. The point that called my close-vote is that like almost all wishes, it's heavily dependent on the interpretation of said wish, especially in the case of a morally insane djinn. This, and wellie, that we don't know what the others would or already have wished for, since you talk about people robbing banks with them ^^'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I can give - is that the advice from the Government would be to wish for the transportation of goods across great distances, instantaneously - eliminating the need for things like long-distance haulage.

This may seem insignificant but when you consider the amount of infrastructure that is used for this (Trucks, roads, Rail freight, Ports, terminals etc.) and the associated 'issues' (not knocking the haulage industry) - things like wear and tear on roads, traffic congestion etc. etc.

This is the most rational way to use wishes in the sense you've outlined that would grow the economy.

(until Amazon captures all the magical beasts and uses them for instant delivery :D )

Comment: Just to point out how difficult this choice would be (if it were on-topic), your suggestion is inflationary and causes the loss of hundreds of thousands (possibly millions) of jobs. It would have the opposite effect. It would destroy the economy by causing a massive depression (too much money, too little employment, entire classes of products suddenly stop selling, causing industries to collapse).

Comment: @JBH Depends on what we call a good economy growth. However, it's sure to cause some chaos during the transition to a state with much less jobs and lack of laws to circumvent it.

Answer (score -2):

Who needs wishes when you have
**Block Chain technology**

Since the issue appears to be people stealing money using wishes, and no meta wishes are allowed, the best way to prevent this is to make sure all your money is stored in the block chain.

Block chain technology is essentially immutable. You can't change the history of the block chain, only newly added transactions.

And with enough participation (since this will apply at a global level), even a Genie wouldn't be able to generate the raw computational power required to overcome the block chain and rewrite its history (specially since you said no Meta wishes are allowed, and finding the next key to add a transaction onto the block chain would require Unknown Knowledge)

Even better yet, If all ownership of items and wills were moved into the blockchain (as potential NFTs) your wish makers would have no choice but to result to good old fashion murder wishes to obtain their vast fortunes.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question...